# Dynamically import a scss depending on the environment/logic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I have two css/scss file i need to load this files in particular page only based on condition

```
Example
if(mydata==“strt”
{
//load one.css/one.scss
}
else
{
//load two.css/two.scss
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this pretty complicated or you can just be simple and namespace your css.

With sass you can nest things easily so just take your one.scss rules wrap them in a one class. Then do the same for two.scss and put the whole thing into an included file:

```
.styles-one {
   // all your styles from one.scss
}

.styles-two {
   // all your styles from one.scss
}
```

When you have done that you can simply set the CSS class on your wrapper rather than trying to dynamically load CSS styles.